# How to iterate and test columns of a data frame in R faster?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a data frame in `R` with 2 variables: `a` and `b`.

I want to test row by row checking if the variable `a` contains the pattern **'OK'**.

If it's `TRUE`, I want to invert the content of the variable `a` and variable `b` in the same row.

The following code is working:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dataframe)){
  if(!is.na(grep('OK', dataframe$a[i])[1])){
    b = dataframe$b[i]
    dataframe$b[i] <- dataframe$a[i]
    dataframe$a[i] <- b
  }
}
```

I'd like to know if is there a better way to have the same result, but faster?

Comment: Don't use `ifelse` inside a loop unless you are looping over columns. The `ifelse` function already acts like a loop over a vector argument. Voting to close as essentially a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I changed the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using vectorized functions in R, you can test all rows in one single function call. You can see that my code was 50x faster in the example below.

In this case, `if_else` is the vectorized version of `ifelse` and `str_detect` is the vectorized version of `grep`. The `tidyverse` packages and pipes supply the functions `select` and `mutate` that make it easy to manipulate data frames with vectorized functions.

```r
library(tidyverse)

n <- 10000
sampledata <- data.frame(aa=rbinom(n, 1, 0.5), b = rep("bvalue", n), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(a = if_else(aa == 0, "nothing", "OK")) %>% 
  select(a, b, -aa)

yourcode <- function(sampledata) {  
  newdata <- sampledata
  for(i in 1:nrow(sampledata)){
    if(!is.na(grep('OK', sampledata$a[i])[1])){
      b <- sampledata$b[i]
      newdata$b[i] <- sampledata$a[i]
      newdata$a[i] <- b
    }
  }
  return(newdata)
}

# using vectorized functions and tidyverse will make your code faster

mycode <- function(sampledata) {
  newdata <- sampledata %>% mutate(new_b = if_else(str_detect(a, "OK"), a, b),
                                   new_a = if_else(str_detect(a, "OK"), b, a)) %>%
    select(-a, -b, a = new_a, b = new_b)
  return(newdata)
  }

system.time(yourcode(sampledata))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    1.46    0.03    1.56
system.time(mycode(sampledata))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.03    0.00    0.03
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Arthur! I'm going to study more this tidyverse. It looks exactly what I need for the job I'm on.

Comment: The best resources are https://www.tidyverse.org/ and https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

Comment: Great! Thank you again!